# vector filling true or false based on the given conditions in R without cycle

Tags: r

I have sample vector and some values:

```
q = c(0.00000000, -0.70218526, -0.60635393,  0.32325554,  -0.45921704,  -0.57336113,  -0.77683717,
  -1.76347868,  -1.90884891,  -0.86157465,  -0.72896622,  -0.86831735,  -0.79357262,  -0.65279976,
  0.39921356,  0.78018094,  0.75703279,  0.70898895,  1.10155383,  0.88428135,  0.81338108,
  0.65611568,  0.89776945, 0.65447442,  0.16289673,  0.19464041,  0.01762445, -0.57663945,
  -1.01231868, -0.81204022, -0.99165533, -0.62666993, -1.05661282, -0.78221866, -0.03129549,  1.04051915)

s = -1.59688
i = -0.6373684
z = 0
```

I need to create a new vector in which boolean values will be filled according to the following conditions:

- if **q** is less than **i** we fill **TRUE** until

  - **q** becomes more than **0** (that is, **z**)
  - or until **q** becomes less than **s**.
- If Filling has stopped due to the condition of the **s** value, then you need to wait until the **q** becomes greater than **0** (that is, **z**) and
- only after that you can start filling **TRUE** again, otherwise fill in **FALSE**

As a result, for this sample data, you should get the following result (I filled it in manually):

```
out <- c(FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                 FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                 FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)

out

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I would like to do it without loops, since they are too slow in R

Comment: @akrun could you describe in more detail what needs to be clarified

Comment: Aren't *"fill TRUE until q becomes more than 0 (that is, z)"* and *"wait until the q becomes greater than 0 (that is, z) and only after that you can start filling TRUE again"* contradictory?

Comment: Pay attention to the condition, I noted there that I need to skip filling TRUE, even if q did not reach zero, only if before this q became less than s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** FURTHER EDIT in view of OP's request to state logic/strategy**

Actually, your conditions are combination of three conditions.  If we create four zones, as I created in the plot above and name the zones as 1 to 4 with

- `1 where q values are >= z`
- `2 where q values are >= i`
- `3 where q values are >= s`
- `4 where q values are < s`

Now, the conditions can be translated as

- `TRUE` when in zone 2 and 3
- But if exited once from these `TRUE` zones, it will become `TRUE` only if it arrives in `zone 3`
- Moreover, if it has hit `zone 4`, it can become TRUE only if it arrives/hits `zone 1`, at least once.

Strategy

- To integrate these all, I used tidyverse piped syntax
- 1. First divide all values in respective zones (say `q1`)
- 2. As a first condition divide zones 2 & 3 in `TRUE` and others in `FALSE
- 3. As second condition, say `c2` , i.e. whether exited from zone 4 and has hit zone 1 or not, mark zone 4 as `F` and zone 1 as `T` rest all as NAs.

  - First value can be `NA` so replace first value, if NA, with c1
- 4. As last condition say `c3` i.e. TRUE when arrive in zone 3, mark 3 as `TRUE` 1 and 4 as `FALSE` and leave zone 2 as `NA` to later-on check whether it arrived here from which zone.

  - First value can be `NA` so replace first value, if NA, with `FALSE`
  - Now only job remains to fill NAs in `c2` and `c3`.  Use `zoo::na.locf` or `tidyr::fill` which fills all NAs will last available value.
  - Your final desired result is combination of all conditions so `c1 & c2 & c3`

```r
q = c(0.00000000, -0.70218526, -0.60635393,  0.32325554,  -0.45921704,  -0.57336113,  -0.77683717,
      -1.76347868,  -1.90884891,  -0.86157465,  -0.72896622,  -0.86831735,  -0.79357262,  -0.65279976,
      0.39921356,  0.78018094,  0.75703279,  0.70898895,  1.10155383,  0.88428135,  0.81338108,
      0.65611568,  0.89776945, 0.65447442,  0.16289673,  0.19464041,  0.01762445, -0.57663945,
      -1.01231868, -0.81204022, -0.99165533, -0.62666993, -1.05661282, -0.78221866, -0.03129549,  1.04051915)

s = -1.59688
i = -0.6373684
z = 0
library(tidyverse)
q %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('q') %>%
  mutate(q1 = case_when(q >= z ~ 1,
                        q >= i ~ 2,
                        q >= s ~ 3,
                        TRUE ~ 4),
         c1 = q1 %in% c(2,3),
         c2 = case_when(q1 == 4 ~ F,
                        q1 == 1 ~ T,
                        TRUE ~ NA),
         c2 = ifelse(row_number() == 1 & is.na(c2), c1, c2),
         c3 = case_when(q1 %in% c(1,4) ~ F,
                        q1 == 3 ~ T,
                        TRUE ~ NA),
         c3 = ifelse(row_number() ==1 & is.na(c3), F, c3)) %>%
  fill(c2, c3) %>%
  transmute(output = c1 & c2 & c3) %>% pull(output)
#>  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

OLD ANSWER

```
#data given
q = c(0.00000000, -0.70218526, -0.60635393,  0.32325554,  -0.45921704,  -0.57336113,  -0.77683717,
      -1.76347868,  -1.90884891,  -0.86157465,  -0.72896622,  -0.86831735,  -0.79357262,  -0.65279976,
      0.39921356,  0.78018094,  0.75703279,  0.70898895,  1.10155383,  0.88428135,  0.81338108,
      0.65611568,  0.89776945, 0.65447442,  0.16289673,  0.19464041,  0.01762445, -0.57663945,
      -1.01231868, -0.81204022, -0.99165533, -0.62666993, -1.05661282, -0.78221866, -0.03129549,  1.04051915)

s = -1.59688
i = -0.6373684
z = 0

#loading libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#creating zones
q1 <- dplyr::case_when(q >= z ~ 1,
                q >= i ~ 2,
                q >= s ~ 3,
                TRUE ~ 4)

#first condition
c1 <- dplyr::case_when(q1 %in% c(2,3) ~ T,
                TRUE ~ F)

#second condition (third in above statements)
c2 <- dplyr::case_when(q1 == 4 ~ F,
                q1 == 1 ~ T,
                TRUE ~ NA)

c2[1] <- ifelse(is.na(c2[1]), c1[1], c2[1])

c2 <- tidyr::fill(data.frame(id = 1:length(q), c2 = c2), c2)$c2

#third condition
c3 <- dplyr::case_when(q1 == 3 ~ T,
          q1 %in% c(1,4) ~ F,
          TRUE ~ NA)

c3[1] <- ifelse(is.na(c3[1]), F, c3[1])

c3 <- tidyr::fill(data.frame(id = 1:length(q), c3 = c3), c3)$c3

#creating output

output <- (c1 & c2 & c3)
> output
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

#check it with your given `out`

> which((c1 & c2 & c3) == out)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

#OR

> which((c1 & c2 & c3) != out)
integer(0)
```

**UPDATE** If you want to use baseR only, use these expressions/codes for `c2` and `c3`

```
#second condition
c2 <- case_when(q1 == 4 ~ F,
                q1 == 1 ~ T,
                TRUE ~ NA)

c2 <- c2[!cumsum(!is.na(c2)) | !is.na(c2)][cumsum(!cumsum(!is.na(c2)) | !is.na(c2))]

#third condition
c3 <- case_when(q1 == 3 ~ T,
          q1 %in% c(1,4) ~ F,
          TRUE ~ NA)

c3 <- c3[!cumsum(!is.na(c3)) | !is.na(c3)][cumsum(!cumsum(!is.na(c3)) | !is.na(c3))]
```

[image]

for new data

```
q <- c(-0.01563733, -0.05829460, -0.05884189, -0.08954093, -0.13268677, -0.31748724, -0.40060792, -0.08515156, -0.14303489, -0.24525535, -0.93842637, -0.77738228, -1.29502715, -0.89000932, -1.49038656, -1.64953167, -1.67114179, -1.47482366, -0.85874778, -1.01021450, -0.90078260, -1.24313333, -0.99053914, -1.11684140, -1.34073045, -1.36406163, -1.25163185, -1.42429376, -1.48127185, -1.79040671, -2.26811789, -1.82124304, -1.85208201, -1.76394637, -1.63173292) 
i = -0.489
s = -1.032
z = 0

#after running the above code
> output
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[17] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[33] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and chart

[image]

for a new vector with random values

```
set.seed(202)
q <- runif(35, -2, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: *q <- c(-0.01563733, -0.05829460, -0.05884189, -0.08954093, -0.13268677, -0.31748724, -0.40060792,
       -0.08515156, -0.14303489, -0.24525535, -0.93842637, -0.77738228, -1.29502715, -0.89000932,
       -1.49038656, -1.64953167, -1.67114179, -1.47482366, -0.85874778, -1.01021450, -0.90078260,
       -1.24313333, -0.99053914, -1.11684140, -1.34073045, -1.36406163, -1.25163185, -1.42429376,
       -1.48127185, -1.79040671, -2.26811789, -1.82124304, -1.85208201, -1.76394637, -1.63173292)*

i = -0.489 , s = -1.032. does not work on new data

Comment: this not correct, first value , not less i, but filling TRUE

Comment: running perfect on a new set of values.  Try it now

Comment: I'd like to start writing TRUE when there is a bottom to up intersection of the `i` value. How can I fix the proposed code to do this?

Comment: @МихаилТабаков, can you provide an example.  It would be better if you open a new question and link that with this thread.